# How can I query all InfluxDB _internal database measurements?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I cannot query following measurements from _internal database of InfluxDB using Influxql:

```
database
write
shard
```

See results for following commands:

```
> show databases
name: databases
name
----
_internal

>use _internal

> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
cq
database
httpd
queryExecutor
runtime
shard
subscriber
tsm1_cache
tsm1_engine
tsm1_filestore
tsm1_wal
write

> select * from database limit 1;
ERR: error parsing query: found fron, expected FROM at line 1, char 10
> select * from write limit 1;
ERR: error parsing query: found WRITE, expected identifier at line 1, char 15
> select * from shard limit 1;
ERR: error parsing query: found SHARD, expected identifier at line 1, char 15
```

But I can successfully query some other measurements

```
> select * from queryExecutor limit 1;
name: queryExecutor
time                hostname              queriesActive queriesExecuted queriesFinished queryDurationNs recoveredPanics
----                --------              ------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
1559923260000000000 localhost.localdomain 0             0               0               0               0
```

How can I query/extract data from _internal database of InfluxDB across all measurements availbale?

Answer (score 1):

um,,,, it's too late... but I'm find a way
In some cases, an expanded identifier error occurs if one of the queries' identifiers is an InfluxQL keyword.To successfully query an identifier that is also a keyword, tie the identifier to a large quote.

```
select * from "database"
```